# Call PHP Script from Auto-complete AJAX JQuery Mobile

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have following auto-complete code to call PHP file via AJAX and get the results in JSON form:

```
$( "#autocomplete_customer" ).on( "listviewbeforefilter", function ( e, data ) {
    var $ul = $( this ),
        $input = $( data.input ),
        value = $input.val(),
        html = "";
    $ul.html( "" );
    if ( value && value.length > 0 ) {
        $ul.html( "<li><div class='ui-loader'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-loading'></span></div></li>" );
        $ul.listview( "refresh" );
        $.ajax({
            url: "SearchCustomer.php",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            crossDomain: true,
    data: {
                term: $input.val()
            }

        })
        .then( function ( response ) {
            $.each( response, function ( i, val ) {
                html += "<li>" + val + "</li>";
            });
            $ul.html( html );
            $ul.listview( "refresh" );
            $ul.trigger( "updatelayout");
        });
    }
});
```

Here is SearchCustomer.php file:

```
<?php
include "config.php";

mysql_select_db($db, $con);
$search = $_GET['term'];    
$result = mysql_query("my SELECT query on basis of $search") or die('Something went wrong');
$json = '[';
    $first = true;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        if (!$first) { $json .=  ','; } else { $first = false; }
        $json .= ".$row['cli_razon_social'].";
    }
    $json .= ']';
    echo $json;
?>
```

I am facing two issues:

1. Results are not returning from PHP file or I am doing it wrong. Please help me to fix it.
2. Currently user cannot select a value from auto-complete list. How can I modify this script to let user select auto-complete value from text field auto-complete `ul` list?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to prepare a json object to send from your PHP file.

Take a look at [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Ideally, you would prepare an associative array and then convert it to a JSON

For example

```
$arr = array();
$arr['name'] = 'PHP';
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Output

```
{
    'name' : 'PHP'
}
```

You can then refer to the name in your JS as

```
.then(function(resp) { console.log(resp.name); }
```

This will output `PHP` in the console.

However, you might be better off using jQuery UI's built in Autocomplete. Please refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11852282/jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-json-and-ajax).

Moreover, your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. You should switch to Prepared Statements to avoid this.

**UPDATE :**

As for your second issue, you can first assign a class to the list items, eg `<li class="autocomp-data">` and then bind a click handler to it.

```
$ul.html( html );
$('.autocomp-data').click(function() {
    $('correct-selector').val($(this).text());
});
```

Please note that depending on where you want to assign the text, you might need to use either `.val()` or `.html()`.

Comment: @ashvinmukhija I solved issue#1 with your help. Can you help me out in issue#2 explained in my post? thanks

Comment: This modification made it possible to show hand cursor while user place mouse on one of value from list but still i need to assign a value to text field when user clicked on selected item:

.then( function ( response ) {
                $.each( response, function ( i, val ) {
                    html += "<li>" + "<a>" + val + "</a>" + "</li>";
                });

any suggestion?

Comment: Answered the second part of your question. Please see the update.