# jQuery UI Autocomplete JSON Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jquery-ui

I use below code for jQuery UI Autocomplete.

```
<script>
$(function() {

    $( "#city" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {

        $.post('<?php echo base_url()?>records/get_village_street_town_name', {
           SourceLanguage: 'SourceLanguage',
           inputVal: $( "#city" ).val()
        },

       function (data) { 
            citydata = jQuery.parseJSON( data );

            response( 

            $.each(citydata, function( index, city ) {
                return city.cityname;
            })

        );


       });



        },
        minLength: 2,
    });
});
</script>
```

Below is the return O/P via the AJAX call.

```
[{"cityname":"ABCDE"},{"cityname":"ABDCE"},{"cityname":"ABEDC"}]
```

The problem is city textbox is not filled with citynames from the AJAX ? How can I fix this ?

I referred below two but didn't help.

[JQuery UI autocomplete with json and ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11852282/jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-json-and-ajax)

[Using jquery ui autocomplete + ajax json data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18218491/using-jquery-ui-autocomplete-ajax-json-data)

Comment: Try `$.map` instead of `$.each`.

Comment: there is no need to $.map() also as there is no data manipulation... is `data` an array of object

Comment: if you can please tell me where the issue is

Comment: You may need to return label: & value:

Comment: @ArunPJohny, excellent point. I never even looked at that function body. :P

Comment: @ChinnuR : I don't think so.

Comment: `citydata = jQuery.parseJSON( data );` is it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code would be

```
<script>
$(function() {

    $( "#city" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {

        $.post('<?php echo base_url()?>records/get_village_street_town_name', {
           SourceLanguage: 'SourceLanguage',
           inputVal: $( "#city" ).val()
        },

       function (data) { 
            citydata = jQuery.parseJSON( data );

            response( 

            $.map( citydata, function( item ) {
                return item.cityname;
            })

        );
       });

        },
        minLength: 2,
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of your JSON code is invalid and the parser does not identify it as object, in the example you declared `[{"cityname":"ABCDE"},{"cityname":"ABDCE"},,{"cityname":"ABEDC"}]` which should be `[{"cityname":"ABCDE"},{"cityname":"ABDCE"},{"cityname":"ABEDC"}]`.