# PHP search function not displaying results

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, mysqli

I've been playing around with PHP and ajax and trying to get it to produce my results. For some reason though, it's not working at all. I will write in some words and nothing will appear.

Code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $( document ).ready( function() {
            $('.searchFunction').keyup( function( event ) {
                var search_term = $(this).attr('value');

        });
    </script>
```

Again, I am not really sure how to fix this. My database is called `ing` and the name of the field is `ingName`.

Comment: nothing at all , Its weird

Comment: @Nevershow2016 your code is running. Check your console. I just verified it. Something wrong with your query.

Comment: @Nevershow2016 got the issue check my code below.

Comment: Try to catch error using `mysql_error($con)` after your query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it: you were not getting text box value here `var search_term = $(this).val();`

The OP was trying to read the value of the text box using `var search_term = $(this).attr('value');`

There was issue in your select query, I have updated it.

Update 1:

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' )
    {
        $conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("could not connect");
        mysql_select_db("test") or die ("could not find db");

        if ( !empty( $_POST['search_term'] ) ) 
        {

            $search_term =  $_POST['search_term'] ;

           $query = mysql_query( "SELECT `ingName` FROM `ing` WHERE `ingName` LIKE '".$search_term.'%', $conn );


            if( $query )
            {
                while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $query ) ) 
                {
                    echo '<li>'.$row['ingName'].'</li>';
                }
            }
        }
        mysql_close( $conn );
        exit();
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Dashboard</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container">
        <input type="text" name='search_term' class="searchFunction">
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <ul class="result"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $( document ).ready( function() {
            $('.searchFunction').keyup( function( event ) {
                var search_term = $(this).val();

                $.post( document.location.href, { search_term:search_term }, function( data ) {
                    $('.result').html( data );

                    $('.result li').click( function( event ) {
                        var result_value = $(this).text();

                        $('.searchFunction').attr('value', result_value );
                        $('.result').html('');
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

  </body>
```

Comment: Can you please explain what changes you made here ?

Comment: You're trying to read an attribute in the element while instead you want the value `var search_term = $(this).val();`

Comment: tRIED this is well and still nothing

Comment: @Nevershow2016 check my updated code. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Howeer it did not add to the box again i am not sure why

Comment: Also ok , sorry i did not save ur work haha, i tried it now again it did not work but the one above works fine and i am not sure hwy

Comment: So when it comes to a dropdown box when i search, when the user clicks on it, it shouild show up in the search box

Comment: Yes so i search for the name apple, it will appear below it, that is fine, when the user clicks on apple, it should automatcally put it in the box were i just searched

Comment: @Nevershow2016 well its a long process then check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11852282/jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-json-and-ajax you will have to call another ajax on text box to fetch data from database and then display it in text box.

Comment: @Nevershow2016 you can try out things and if getting stuck open up a separate question I shall assist you with that as well.

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala Thanks so much also this is the thing i was trying to do : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4fwOCgenuXI

Comment: @Nevershow2016 please accept the answer if it helped you. Also please let me know if you require assistance in future questions. Always there to help!

Comment: @Nevershow2016 check this simple example for autocomplete http://jsfiddle.net/rdworth/ebduf/

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala yes that is what i want :) i tried to get it work but no joy :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104909/discussion-between-fakhruddin-ujjainwala-and-nevershow2016).

Comment: @Nevershow2016 could you open a new question and post your code there? SHare me the link to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Run your query in the MySQL command line, and try to get results. Do you get a response?

Next point: you use wrong concatenation. I mean, change this

```
,$row['ingName'],
```

to this

```
. $row['ingName'] .
```

Comment: This may be one of the reason. *Good Catch*

Comment: Were should this go>?

Comment: echo '<li>',$row['ingName'],'</li>'; to echo '<li>'.$row['ingName'].'</li>';

Answer (score 0):

Select your textbox by id or class. Here I am doing it using id, getting the value of the textbox when a key is pressed, and passing the entered value in ajax code.

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' )
    {
        $conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("could not connect");
        mysql_select_db("test") or die ("could not find db");

        if ( !empty( $_POST['search_term'] ) ) 
        {

            $search_term = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['search_term'] );

            $query = mysql_query( "SELECT `ingName` FROM `ing` WHERE `ingName` LIKE '$search_term%'", $conn );


            if( $query )
            {
                while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $query ) ) 
                {
                    echo '<li>'.$row['ingName'].'</li>';
                }
            }
        }
        mysql_close( $conn );
        exit();
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Dashboard</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container">
        <input type="text" name='search_term' id="search_term" class="searchFunction">
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <ul class="result"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $( document ).ready( function() 
        {
            $('.searchFunction').keyup( function( event ) 
            {
                var search_term = $("#search_term").val();

                $.post( document.location.href, { search_term:search_term }, function( data ) 
                {
                    $('.result').html( data );

                    $('.result li').click( function( event ) 
                    {
                        var result_value = $(this).text();
                        $('.searchFunction').attr('value', result_value );
                        $('.result').html('');
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: An Explanation To This Answer Will Be More Useful. What Changes You Did In Code & Why It Will Work. Don't Simply Write "*Try This Example*".

Comment: This is great it actually worked perfectly, but yes, what changes were made , jut so i know

Comment: @PareshGami there is only 1 thing wrong, when u click on it, it does not appear in the box

Comment: So it will become a drop down box and its there but when i click on it , it should show up in the search box